# How do i access browser's search bar to search my exact keywords on google and then open the results in a new widow?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome, dom

I cannot use the google query string as it is too complex.And making a get request only takes me to a website.But i want to search the exact keywords on google using javascript or html only.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How could you find https://www.google.co.in/search?q=arnold+parge complex? It is simple. Or is your search content complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Shorten it in any string by using it like this:

https://www.google.com/search?query=Your_Query_String

Answer (score 1):

Every Google Search can be formatted into a URL string according to specifications on Google's Website: https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html

From a website on most browsers, you will not be able to jump out of the web view to the URL bar, change the parameters, and load in a new window.

You are better off formatting the URL string as an `<a href="">` link with a `target="_blank`.